# Delete rows in Data table

Tags: r

I have a twitter dataset and I would like to delete the whole row if the word lee is in the tweet. I have this code, but I still get the same amount of entries.

```
dt.cleaned <- dt.tweets.filtered[body != "lee",]
```

What code do I need in order to remove the whole row if the word lee is in the body?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
dt.cleaned <- dt.tweets.filtered[!grepl("lee", body)]
```

assuming that 'dt.tweets.filtered' is a `data.table` object.  If it is a `data.frame`, either convert to `data.table` with `setDT` i.e. `setDT(dt.tweets.filtered)` or use `base R` methods,

```
dt.cleaned <- dt.tweets.filtered[!grepl("lee", body), ]
```